# Login to secured website programmatically

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have setup the help for my Firemonkey app on a password-secured website hosted by site44.com.

Passing the password as part of the URL doesn't work with certain browsers because they consider it insecure. So I tried the following code. This doesn't work either. Function Login returns the login HTML of the website but does not actually log me in. Can you tell me where my code is wrong?

```
procedure TMyMainForm.OnlineHelp1Execute(Sender: TObject);
function Login: string;
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  Request: TStringList;
  Response: TMemoryStream;
begin
  Result := '';
  try
    Response := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      Request := TStringList.Create;
      try
        Request.Add('password=mypassword');
        IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
        try
          IdHTTP.IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP);
          IdHTTP.AllowCookies := True;
          IdHTTP.HandleRedirects := False;
          IdHTTP.Post('https://mysite.site44.com/', Request, Response);
          Result := IdHTTP.Get('https://mysite.site44.com/');
        finally
          IdHTTP.Free;
        end;
      finally
        Request.Free;
      end;
    finally
      Response.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
  end;
end;

begin
 ShowMessage(Login);
end;
```

Comment: Typically, you would `Get()` the URL of the login page (so you can get any cookies associated with it), parse the HTML `<form>` for required fields (unless you know them ahead of time), then `Post()` the necessary field values (and cookies) to the login URL. The code you showed is not doing that first step. If the `Get()` after `Post()` is returning the login HTML then the credentials likely failed, and the HTML might have an error message in it saying as much

Comment: @RemyLebeau. I made some adjustments and I think I managed to log on because I was able to return the index.html page using IdHTTP.Get (whereas before I was only returning the login HTML). But what I wanted was to open the index.html page in the default browser. Please could you point me in the right direction to doing that?

Comment: @Duns: you can use the TWebbrowser component for this (although you will be opening a different can of worms :) )